# How to stake ETH for Ethereum 2.0?

Tags: proof-of-stake, eth-2.0

How can I stake ETH in Ethereum 2.0 network to earn staking rewards? How much ETH to I need? How much I can earn? How long do I need to wait to get my reward?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ethereum 2.0 phase zero staking has been live since December 2020.

Ethereum 2.0 rewards proof of stake validators with [block production rewards](https://codefi.consensys.net/blog/rewards-and-penalties-on-ethereum-20-phase-0#:%7E:text=Rewards%20and%20penalties-,Slashing,blocks%20for%20the%20same%20slot). The amount of reward depends on the network participation: more there are validators, less one single validator can earn. You can calculate [the estimated earnings](https://beaconcha.in/calculator) with the current validator rate.

Depending on the staking mode (see below) your is locked until further Ethereum 2.0 launch phase milestones can be reached. This might be years away, so I recommend sticking to a staking model where you have tokenised pool shares. Tokenised shares allow you to [trade your Ethereum staking position](https://capitalgram.com/posts/ethereum-2.0-staking-and-stakewise/) earlier - your staked ETH (stETH) is liquid.

There are brought three primary ways to stake ETH:

- Though a tokenised staking pool services with tokenised staking shares: [Stakewise](https://stakewise.io/), [Lido](https://lido.fi/), [Stkr](https://eth2.ankr.com/), [Stafi](https://stafi.io/), [Rocketpool](https://www.rocketpool.net/) - these staking pool shares can be traded in decentralised finance (DeFi) services
- Staking yourself: Run [an Ethereum validator yourself](https://ethereum.org/en/eth2/staking/) and full minimum 32 ETH capital commitment  needed
- Staking through a centralised exchange: Kraken, [Coinbase](https://blog.coinbase.com/ethereum-2-0-staking-rewards-are-coming-soon-to-coinbase-a25d8ac622d5)

If you are going to stake yourself you need some advanced IT knowledge, either system administrator, software developer or similar level. Full 32 ETH capital commitment is also needed, whereas staking pools allow you to stake with less amount and distribute staking across multiple participants.

Staking through a centralised exchange has [the highest counterparty risk](https://capitalgram.com/posts/ethereum-2.0-staking-and-stakewise/), is least diversifying for the Ethereum network vitality and is against the decentralised spirit of Ethereum.